# Transcation is confirmed 13/6(needed) but still red in bitcoin core and not recieved in wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've used BITCOIN CORE to recieved bought BTC.
And then I've sent this to a "dwWallet" but still I've not recieved the funds, and I'm absolutely sure, it's not a mirror scam shit, and so on.

Well, the transaction it self, is confirmed by 13 , and needed for 6. Have been about 2 hours now, and still not even see in the wallet any "incoming soon" or something.

What, to do? or how long can it take, I thought when confirmed it's instant, you only need to wait for the confirmations and then it wouldn't be any delays, but I can be wrong for sure. But never ever been struggeling with this issue, always done in 40min before.

And I can see in BITCOIN CORE - it's marked confirmed, but still marked red in the overview.
TXID:  f580e936e3fbb3392b2aa3e53babb4af82bc94a899d23e7f7b8a995a8cec8693

Answer (score 1):

Red just means that it’s an outflow of funds, while black is an inbound payment. Transaction f580e936e3fbb3392b2aa3e53babb4af82bc94a899d23e7f7b8a995a8cec8693 is confirmed on the blockchain. It sounds like “dwWallet” is out-of-sync and has not correctly recognized that it was paid. I assume you have verified that the address you sent to belongs to the intended wallet?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, there nothiung wrong with adress nor scam, thats for sure, but incredible how long time it can take since the confirmations are done?!

Comment: I’ve never heard of "dwwallet" nor can I find anything about it.—Either way it sounds that the software at the receiving end is at fault. Try to find whether it has a function to force a resync or rescan.